# Is there an easier way to convert javascript object to dynamodb update expression?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using nodejs `aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb` library with dynamodb. I need to update an item in the table. Below is the sample code to update an item:

```
params = {
    TableName:table,
    Key:{
        "year": year,
        "title": title
    },
    UpdateExpression: "set info.rating = info.rating + :val",
    ExpressionAttributeValues:{
        ":val": 1
    },
    ReturnValues:"UPDATED_NEW"
};
```

I will have to specify each attribute in `info` in `UpdateExpression`. My `info` object is very big and I am looking for an easier way to do that. Is there a build-in method to support update an object to dynamodb item? something like:

```
params = {
    TableName:table,
    Key:{
        "year": year,
        "title": title
    },
    Item: info
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Document Client:

> Version 2.2.0 of the AWS SDK for JavaScript introduces support for the
> document client abstraction in the AWS.DynamoDB namespace. The
> document client abstraction makes it easier to read and write data to
> Amazon DynamoDB with the AWS SDK for JavaScript. Now you can use
> native JavaScript objects without annotating them as AttributeValue
> types.

For example:

```
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'us-west-2'});

var params = {
    Item: {
        hashkey: 'key',
        boolAttr: true,
        listAttr: [1, 'baz', true]
        mapAttr: {
            foo: 'bar'
        }
    },
    TableName: 'table'
};

docClient.put(params, function(err, data){
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else console.log(data);
});
```

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/announcing-the-amazon-dynamodb-document-client-in-the-aws-sdk-for-javascript/

Comment: Does it support partial update? It seems that it overwrite the whole item with the new one?

Answer (score 2):

The answer given by E.J. Brennan is great for cases where it's ok to **replace** the entire item. DocumentClient eases the hassle of dealing with DynamoDB attribute types, but the example given uses the `put` method. According to the docs `put` passes through to `putItem` which

> Creates a new item, or replaces an old item with a new item

That means that it's not going to help with partial updates to existing items where you don't already have the full record (and can get away with a full replacement). For partial updates you have to use `updateItem`, or it's DocumentClient counterpart, `update`.

The AWS labs has [published a utility](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-data-mapper-js/tree/master/packages/dynamodb-expressions#update-expressions) to help with constructing update expressions to use with `updateItem`. Since I generally prefer to use DocumentClient, I unmarshall values with the utility function provided by DynamoDB's Converter (yes, I know it's a bit a back and forth, but it makes testing easier).

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const db = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
const { UpdateExpression, ExpressionAttributes } = require('@aws/dynamodb-expressions');
const { unmarshall } = AWS.DynamoDB.Converter;

const updateExpressionProps = ({ category, classification }) => {
  attributes = new ExpressionAttributes();
  expression = new UpdateExpression();

  expression.set('category', category);
  expression.set('classification', classification);

  return {
    UpdateExpression: expression.serialize(attributes),
    ExpressionAttributeNames: attributes.names,
    ExpressionAttributeValues: unmarshall(attributes.values),
  };
};

const updateRequest = async ({ id, subject, category, classification }) =>
  await db
    .update({
      TableName: 'table-name',
      Key: {
        id,
        subject,
      },
      ...updateExpressionProps({ category, classification }),
    })
    .promise();
```

This bit of code *only* updates the `category` and `classification` attributes on the record identified with `id` and `subject` without the hassle of manually building a correct UpdateExpression string. This example could easily be generalized into something reusable throughout your project.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the following utility method to convert a given object to UpdateExpression (SET only), ExpressionAttributeNames, and ExpressionAttributeValues.

```
const convertToCompositePathObj = (obj: Record<any, any>) => {
  const res: Record<string, string | number | []> = {};

  const getPropertyPath = (obj: Record<any, any>, current = "") => {
    for (let key in obj) {
      const value = obj[key];

      const newKey = current ? [current, key].join(".") : key;

      if (value && typeof value === "object" && !Array.isArray(value)) {
        getPropertyPath(value, newKey);
      } else res[newKey] = value;
    }
  };

  getPropertyPath(sampleObject);

  return res;
};

const generateDynamoDbUpdateExpression = (obj: Record<any, any>) => {
  const compositePathObj = convertToCompositePathObj(sampleObject);

  let counter = 0;

  let updateExpression = "SET ";

  const expressionAttNamesMap: any = {};

  const expressionAttValuesMap: any = {};

  for (let k in compositePathObj) {
    const newUpdateExpression = k
      .split(".")
      .map((item) => {
        const attName = `#${item}`;
        if (!expressionAttNamesMap[attName]) {
          expressionAttNamesMap[attName] = item;
        }
        return attName;
      })
      .join(".")
      .concat(`= :${counter} AND `);

    expressionAttValuesMap[`:${counter}`] = compositePathObj[k];

    counter += 1;

    updateExpression += newUpdateExpression;
  }

  updateExpression = updateExpression.substring(0, updateExpression.length - 5);

  return {
    UpdateExpression: updateExpression,
    ExpressionAttributeNames: expressionAttNamesMap,
    ExpressionAttributeValues: expressionAttValuesMap
  };
};

// example usage:

const sampleObject = {
  name: {
    first: "John",
    last: "Doe"
  },
  address: {
    line1: "123 test st.",
    line2: "Apt 123",
    city: "Los Angeless",
    state: "CA",
    zip: 92763
  },
  phone: 8675768475
};

console.log(generateDynamoDbUpdateExpression(sampleObject));



 /** 
    *****OUTPUT*****
{
    UpdateExpression: "SET #name.#first= :0 AND #name.#last= :1 AND #address.#line1= :2 AND #address.#line2= :3 AND #address.#city= :4 AND #address.#state= :5 AND #address.#zip= :6 AND #phone= :7",
    ExpressionAttributeNames:{
    #name: "name"
    #first: "first"
    #last: "last"
    #address: "address"
    #line1: "line1"
    #line2: "line2"
    #city: "city"
    #state: "state"
    #zip: "zip"
    #phone: "phone"
},
    ExpressionAttributeValues:{
    :0: "John"
    :1: "Doe"
    :2: "123 test st."
    :3: "Apt 123"
    :4: "Los Angeless"
    :5: "CA"
    :6: 92763
    :7: 8675768475 
}
}
    
**/
```

PS: I wrote this in a hurry so please excuse the formatting and `any` types.

https://codesandbox.io/s/aws-dynamic-update-expression-set-33tye7?file=/src/index.ts